# Excel macro fails when linked to a shape but works using a command button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long-running Excel 2019 file that suddenly stopped working correctly. A set of shapes are linked to macros (defined as public Subs) - clicking these has started to generate the following error

*Cannot run the macro "abc". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.*

Now, if I instead link a regular command button to the same macro, it runs fine.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890212/running-excel-macro-using-button-not-working) is helpful.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it thanks.